# Optimizing a determinant

Tags: pr.probability, oc.optimization-and-control

Any vector is assumed to be a column vector by default. Suppose $f(\mathbf{x})$ is the $d$-dimensional standard Gaussian density. I am interested in the following optimization problem:
$$
\max_g  ~\det \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T f(\mathbf{x}) g(\mathbf{x})  d \mathbf{x}\right),
$$
where $\det$  stands for the determinant, and the maximization is taken over all measurable $g$ such that $0\le g\le 1$ and
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}  f(\mathbf{x})g(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}=1/2.
$$

Remark 1:
My conjecture is that the maximizer $g$ is the indicator function of the complement of a ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$ of a suitable radius, but I could not find a proof.

Remark 2: It would be even useful to only prove that this optimization problem has a solution, namely, there exists such a $g$ which attains the maximum.

Comment: The determinant is bounded by the trace divided by $d$ to the $d$-th power and the equality is achieved on the multiples of identity. The maximal trace is trivially attained for $g$ you suggested and the resulting matrix is a multiple of identity. Am I missing some subtlety?

Comment: Never thought about the trace argument. Thanks. If you are willing to put your comment as answer I would check it.